# Should I totally hide the internal class in my C++ header file when designing my SDK?

Tags: c++, pimpl-idiom

I am designing a SDK written in C++.
I have a question: could or should I totally hide the internal class in my public C++ header file?

The code snippets are like the following (in the header file *MyPublicClass.h*):

```
namespace PublicNamespace
{
   namespace InternalNamespace
   {
      class MyInternalClass;
   }

   class MyPublicClass
   {
      public:
         void SomeMemberFunc();
         ...

      private:
         std::shared_ptr<InternalNamespace::MyInternalClass> mImpl;
   }
}
```

Per [the C++ PImpl design pattern](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) (and also many other materials from Google), it is OK to put the InternalNamespace::MyInternalClass into the public header.

My thought is: it looks unnecessary to let the external users know the internal namespace InternalNamespace, and also the class MyInternalClass. So I want to use **void** to replace the type **InternalNamespace::MyInternalClass**.

That's to say, for my case, I use std::shared_ptr<*void*> as the type of the data member ***mImpl***, and in the .cpp file, use std::static_pointer_cast<*InternalNamespace::MyInternalClass*>(mImpl) to convert it to the actual class.
(Yeah, I know there is a little cost with this conversion but please ignore it).

Is this design correct or proper? Thanks all.

Comment: *My thought is: it looks unnecessary to let the external users know the internal namespace InternalNamespace,*  -- Why do you think it looks unnecessary?  Many, if not most C++ libraries use namespaces and let the user know what namespace things are located.

Comment: Thanks. My original thought was: the internal type couldn't be used by the external users, so the external user wouldn't mind even if didn't know the internal type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `void` or `void *` unless there is absolutely no alternative -- using void-pointers prevents the compiler from catching mistakes at compile-time, and leads to pain and suffering.

Using a clearly-labelled InternalNamespace should be good enough (assuming the programmers using your API aren't deliberately looking for trouble -- and if they are, there are plenty of other ways for them to find it anyway), although if you wanted to hide `MyInternalClass` entirely from calling code, you could instead make it an inner-class of `MyPublicClass`, i.e. something like this:

```
namespace PublicNamespace
{
   class MyPublicClass
   {
      public:
         void SomeMemberFunc();
         ...

      private:
         class MyInternalClass 
         {
            [...]
         };

         std::shared_ptr<MyInternalClass> mImpl;
    }
}
```

Since it's declared in the `private` section of `MyPublicClass`, no calling code outside of `MyPublicClass` would be able to access it at all.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. I don't want the external user to know the internal type thus I mentioned in this thread to hide. So looks it is a good or correct design to still let the internal types be present in my  SDK public header file, right?

Comment: If the compiler won’t allow the user to reference the internal class in his code, that accomplishes the goal of preventing the user’s code from depending on the internal class’s existence or implementation details; so yes, it is sufficient for the purpose.